# I want to prove that multivariate normal distribution maximizes the entropy

Tags: entropy

I was going through probability higher than I am being taught I was trying this problem ,

Show that the multivariate normal distribution maximizes the entropy over all distributions
with the same covariance matrix.

Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Explanations are available in [these notes](http://pillowlab.princeton.edu/teaching/statneuro2018/slides/notes08_infotheory.pdf) and in [these notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/entropypost.pdf)

Comment: I am stuck due to multi-variable constraints

Comment: I recommend that you begin by trying to generalize a proof for the single-variable case and then update your question to let us know where exactly in the proof you get stuck

Comment: multivariate maximum entropy is discussed in this article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X07001005

Comment: hypothesis testing approach to multivariate maximum entropy for financial time series https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-67536-y